# AddEventListener is executed twice

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am working with Django and Js, and I am trying to get the code to switch the checked attribute of an element so that it changes the category during the creation of an entry in the form, but when clicking on the element, addEventListener is executed twice and, thus, first adds the checked attribute to the element but then immediately removes it

Code:

`form`

```
<div class="new-post-header">
    <div class="new-post-functions">
        <button type="submit" class="save"><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon></button>
        <div class="categories">
            <div class="first-category">{{ form.category.0 }}</div>
            <div class="second-category">{{ form.category.1 }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="new-post-content">
    <div class="new-title">{{ form.title }}</div>
    <div class="new-description">{{ form.description }}</div>
</div>
```

`js`

```
const firstLabel = document.querySelector('[for="id_category_0"]')
const secondLabel = document.querySelector('[for="id_category_1"]')
const firstInput = document.querySelector('input[value="1"]')
const secondInput = document.querySelector('input[value="2"]')

secondInput.hasAttribute('checked')
? localStorage.setItem('secondInput', true)
: localStorage.setItem('secondInput', false)

secondLabel.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let secondInputItem = localStorage.getItem('secondInput')
    if (secondInputItem === 'false') {
        firstLabel.innerHTML = `<input type="radio" name="category" value="1" required="" id="id_category_0"><ion-icon name="bookmark-outline"></ion-icon>`
        secondLabel.innerHTML = `<input type="radio" name="category" value="2" required="" id="id_category_1" checked="checked"><ion-icon name="archive-outline"></ion-icon>`
        localStorage.setItem('secondInput', true)
        console.log(true)
    } else {
        firstLabel.innerHTML = `<input type="radio" name="category" value="1" required="" id="id_category_0" checked="checked"><ion-icon name="bookmark-outline"></ion-icon>`
        secondLabel.innerHTML = `<input type="radio" name="category" value="2" required="" id="id_category_1"><ion-icon name="archive-outline"></ion-icon>`
        localStorage.setItem('secondInput', false)
        console.log(false)
    }
})
```

Simply put, I have a category model, each message should have its own category when created, and I want the first time I click on secondLabel, the message accepts the category with number 2, and the second time it is clicked, it returns the category with number 1, and so on in a circle

Comment: First you need to put a console.log in `addEventListener` to make sure it run twice. Second, seems like you're lacking closing tag for the `input`. Not sure if these can help you debug.

Comment: I don't think you've shown all the relevant javascript - what is `secondInput` what is `firstLabel` what is `secondLabel` etc

Comment: @bird , I checked using console.log() and addEventListener is indeed executed twice

Comment: are you loading the script twice somehow? we can't tell from what you posted

Comment: @JaromandaX, No, I'm not uploading

Comment: not sure what the significance of not "uploading" is ... I asked are you somehow loading the script twice ... if you can see `addEventListener` is being CALLED twice (not the callback), and the code you've shown is accurate, then the only way that can happen is if you load that code twice

Comment: @JaromandaX, sorry, I don't speak a foreign language well, I meant that the code is loaded once, I have a large js file, I would notice if all other functions were executed twice too

Comment: and yet, here we are ... is the code in the question "top level" or is it inside some other function? a `console.log` just before `secondLabel.addEventListener` outputs once or twice?

Comment: this is a separate code and it is not inside another function. outputs once